# Oracle TNS Protocol Adapter Erro

Tags: c#, oracle11g, visual-studio-2010, tnsnames

I have a remote Oracle 11G server that I can connect to with SQL Plus and through Visual Studio's server explorer. However, when I use the same connection string in my C# code, I'm getting ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error.

My connection string looks like this (already trying the completed expanded version):

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.18.99.99)(PORT=1521))    (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MYORADB)));User Id=myuserid;Password=MyPasswd;
```

My initial attempts to connect with a hostname instead of IP resulted in:

```
ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
```

With the IP, address I get the protocol adapter error

```
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode,     OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
at TestConnection.Form1.btnTest_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I am using Oracle.DataAccess version 2.112.1.0 from the 11g client install directory.

Is there something different between the way the server explorer connects than from within the code?

Comment: Have you tried (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.18.99.99)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MYORADB))) as your data source? You may also want to turn on tracing http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/featConfig.htm

Comment: That's the string I'm currently using. Can I turn tracing on from within that string?

Comment: No, but you can modify your app.config similar to the link and that should spit out a trace file. Do you have multiple Oracle clients installed(32 & 64 bit)?

Comment: Only a 32bit client, but the GAC as Oracle.DataAccess DLLs for 64 and 32. My project references the 32bit 11g client, not the GAC dlls. However, I had tried the others with the same result.

Comment: Do you have a sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora in <client_home>\network\admin? The only other thing I can think of is use (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = MYORADB)) instead of SERVICE_NAME.

Comment: Try this  `DATA SOURCE=172.18.99.99:1521/MYORADB` 
Also, verify you have your TNSNAMES.ora and SQLNET.ora configured properly to work with your remote server.